# Multi level inheritance in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

I want to implement Multi Level Inheritance in my Vb.Net application.
I have a base form named Base_Level0 which contains some methods, properties etc.
Now one more form named Base_Level1 which inherits Base_Level0.

These 2 forms are the base forms.

Now my actual form named Form1 inherits Base_Level1.
This Form1 contains a form Load event which is not fired.

But if Form1 inherits Base_Level0 directly the load event is fired.
Then why does the load event dose not fire with multi level inheritance.

These 3 lists are UserControls.

```
***Base List Level0

Public Class frmNewBaseList_Level0
'
'
Private Sub frmNewBaseList_Level0_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub
'
'
End Class

***Base List Level1

Public Class frmNewBaseList_Level1
    Inherits frmNewBaseList_Level0
'
'
Private Sub frmNewBaseList_Level1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub
'
'
End Class

***Actual List 

Public Class frmCustomersList
    Inherits frmNewBaseList_Level1
'
'
Private Sub frmCustomersList_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub
'
'
End Class

The code from where i add these list to my main form is given below:

  Public Sub setMDIChild(ByVal sMDIChild As UserControl, ByVal sMDIParent As Form)

            sMDIChild.Parent = sMDIParent
            sMDIChild.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            sMDIChild.Show()
            sMDIChild.BringToFront()
            EnableSearch = True
 End Sub
```

frmCustomersList call in the MDI form is as below:

```
        If (ofrmCustomer Is Nothing) Then
            ofrmCustomer = New frmCustomersList
        End If
        setMDIChild(ofrmCustomer, Me)
```

Comment: post the actual code rather than a vague description of it.

Comment: I really hope you're not using names like `Base_Level1` and `Form1` in your actual code.